# individual patient data (ipd) meta-analysis

Tags: r, stata

I am interested in conducting a ipd meta analysis, exploring pre and post treatment effects (no control arm) of an intervention, to assess effectiveness across different exploratory studies.

I have already run a multi-level model using Stata, but I do not know how to proceed with the next steps. The resources for conducting this analysis using R seem to be more comprehensive, so I am thinking to just do the whole thing in R.

I would like to know what steps I would need to take to conduct a one-stage analysis. So,  how do I conduct a multi-level model using R?
What should I do after this, I understand that I need to use the `rma.mv()` function, but I am not so familiar with this (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2017-July/000044.html).

Please can anyone who has conducted a ipd meta-analysis kindly, in the  simplest of terms, explain me the steps involved so I can do this myself in R.

I can also explain my data in more detail if needed.

Comment: Is there are reason why you need to use `rma.mv`? Please describe the variables you want to model and how they are distrubuted.

Comment: I want to model differences in indiviual mean scores, including study type as asecond level. My main query here is to establish how to conduct a ipd meta analysis

Comment: From my and [their](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-meta-analysis/2017-July/000044.html) understanding, `rma.mv` is designed to work with aggregated data (e.g. having one effect size per study and there is no subject level data available) emphasizing my answer using `lmer`  instead. You might wanna use `(studyType | study)` as a random factor. Since you are conducting an IPD, we do not need fancy methods to estimate variances here.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic way to do a mixed model in R is using `lmer`. Here, the     Average reaction time (ms) is significantly influenced by the Number of days of sleep deprivation controlled for the subject modeled as a random factor:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(lmerTest)
#> Loading required package: lme4
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lmerTest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lme4':
#> 
#>     lmer
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     step
data("sleepstudy", package="lme4")
lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy) %>%
  summary()
#> Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
#> lmerModLmerTest]
#> Formula: Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject)
#>    Data: sleepstudy
#> 
#> REML criterion at convergence: 1786.5
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -3.2257 -0.5529  0.0109  0.5188  4.2506 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  Subject  (Intercept) 1378.2   37.12   
#>  Residual              960.5   30.99   
#> Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>             Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 251.4051     9.7467  22.8102   25.79   <2e-16 ***
#> Days         10.4673     0.8042 161.0000   13.02   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>      (Intr)
#> Days -0.371
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

`(1|Subject)` indicates to have one intercept per subject and they share a common slope. `(group|Subject)` would refer to have one slope per group of subjects.